# R: change/match data types of common columns between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have this data frame:

```
# Original data frame
df_1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10, 5), 
                   b = letters[1:5], 
                   c = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, replace = TRUE),
                   d = 6:10)
#  a b     c  d
#1 7 a FALSE  6
#2 9 b  TRUE  7
#3 3 c  TRUE  8
#4 5 d  TRUE  9
#5 6 e  TRUE 10
```

I also have a second data frame that has some columns in common with the first:

```
# Data frame with wonky data types
df_2 <- data.frame(a = as.character(sample(1:10, 5)), 
                   foo = 1:5,
                   b = letters[1:5], 
                   bar = runif(5),
                   c = as.character(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5, replace = TRUE)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#   a foo b       bar     c
#1 10   1 a 0.1185343 FALSE
#2  5   2 b 0.3081978  TRUE
#3  6   3 c 0.4409280  TRUE
#4  8   4 d 0.5081508 FALSE
#5  7   5 e 0.7404537 FALSE
```

Notice that the columns that `df_2` has in common with `df_1` (i.e., `a`, `b`, `c`) do not necessarily have the same data type as the corresponding columns in `df_1`. For example, `a` in `df_1` is of type `integer`, while `a` in `df_2` is of type `character`.

What I'd like to do is convert all columns in `df_2` that are also present in `df_1` to the data type of the `df_1` column.

My first hope was that I could bind them and that would automatically do the conversion:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df_1, df_2)
```

but, no:

> Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) :    Column `a` can't be converted from
>   integer to character

So, my next attempt was to figure out which columns are in common:

```
# Common columns
common <- names(df_2)[names(df_2) %in% names(df_1)]
```

Now, if I wanted to convert them all to `numeric` I might use,

```
df_2 %>% mutate_at(common, as.numeric)
```

but they are all different data types, so I need to use the corresponding data type. I think that somehow I could use `as` passing the corresponding class as derived from `lapply(df_1, class)`, but the details elude me. I think that there must be a simple, elegant solution and I'm overthinking this, but I've had no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot see an elegant solution other than perhaps call to `Reduce` but it appears that (surprising to me) there is no `as( obj, "factor")`.

Comment: @42 is that why this doesn't work? `lapply(common, function(x)df_2 %>% select(x) %>% mutate_all(funs(as(., var.types[[x]]))))` where `var.types <- lapply(df_1, class)`

Comment: Yes, ... when I tried using that approach albeit with old-school loops I got the error message: `no method or default for coercing “character” to “factor”`.

Comment: @42-, same here, which is why I thought I would try the `match.fun` approach.

Comment: Well, Sir Mahto, that just shows yet again that you're smarter than I. (Welcome back by the way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something using `match.fun` would work:

```
str(df_1) ## The source classes...
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ a: int  4 2 5 9 8
#  $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ c: logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  $ d: int  6 7 8 9 10

str(df_2) ## Before conversion
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ a  : chr  "8" "10" "9" "3" ...
#  $ foo: int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ b  : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#  $ bar: num  0.294 0.34 0.372 0.459 0.736
#  $ c  : chr  "FALSE" "TRUE" "TRUE" "FALSE" ...
```

This is the conversion step:

```
df_2[common] <- lapply(common, function(x) {
  match.fun(paste0("as.", class(df_1[[x]])))(df_2[[x]])
})

str(df_2) ## After conversion
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ a  : int  8 10 9 3 1
#  $ foo: int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ b  : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ bar: num  0.294 0.34 0.372 0.459 0.736
#  $ c  : logi  FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: So, by patching together the function name like this it sidesteps the issue that @42 raised that "there is no `as( obj, "factor")`"?

Comment: This breaks when a column is a datetime because it has two types `c("POSIXct" "POSIXt")`

Comment: The solution is that you need to take the first value from the result of the class() function like this: `class(df_1[[x]])[1]`.